# How to create bigquery array<string> dynamically using bigquery client API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to create bq routine dynamically using bq client, as part of that we need to create bigquery supported arguments like INT64,STRING etc, we need to create array also , please advise if any idea on that. by using bigquery.enums we are getting only array not 'array'

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query by using [array parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-params-arrays#bigquery_query_params_arrays-python) when dealing with arrays and **BigQuery client**.

Here's a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest) for querying using BigQuery client and make sure that you have already set up your authentication.

A documentation about [BigQuery Data types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) might also help you deal with INT64, STRING, etc.